# Load tag file xml PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have an XML file and wanted to get the values that are in the `<arquivo>` tag,

```
<Listings>
    <Listing>
      <id>1</id>
      <endereco>abc</endereco>
      <Media>
        <foto>
          <arquivo>foto1.jpg</arquivo>
        </foto>
        <foto>
          <arquivo>foto2.jpg</arquivo>
        </foto>
      </Media>
    </Listing>
    <Listing>
      <id>2</id>
      <endereco>rua X</endereco>
      <Media>
        <foto>
          <arquivo>...</arquivo>
        </foto>
        <foto>
          <arquivo>...</arquivo>
        </foto>
      </Media>
    </Listing>
</Listings>
```

but I'm not sure what's wrong with my PHP

```
$listings = simplexml_load_file("file.xml");

foreach ($listings as $listing):

    echo 'endereco: ' . trim($listing->endereco) . "<br>";

    foreach($listing->Media as $items):
        foreach($items as $item):
            echo 'Image: ' . trim($item) . "<br>";
        endforeach;
    endforeach;

endforeach;
```

The result of my code is

```
endereco: abc
Imagem: 
Imagem: 
endereco: rua X
Imagem: 
Imagem:
```

but I hoped it would be

```
endereco: abc
Imagem: foto1.jpg
Imagem: foto2.jpg
endereco: rua X
Imagem: ...
Imagem: ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enter every level of the structure like you did for `enderco`. Take a look at:

```
$x = new simplexmlelement('<Listings>
<Listing>
  <id>1</id>
  <endereco>abc</endereco>
  <Media>
    <foto>
      <arquivo>foto1.jpg</arquivo>
    </foto>
    <foto>
      <arquivo>foto2.jpg</arquivo>
    </foto>
  </Media>
</Listing></Listings>');
foreach ($x as $listing):
    echo 'endereco: ' . trim($listing->endereco) . "<br>";
    foreach($listing->Media as $items):
            foreach($items->foto as $foto):
                echo 'Image: ' . trim($foto->arquivo) . "<br>";
            endforeach;
        endforeach;
endforeach;
```

https://3v4l.org/0bcfj

Answer (score 0):

Use a foreach loop around the root elements, and then use an XPath query for easier access to the inner elements. It's still pretty hacky with two foreach loops, but it should work fine.

```
<?php
$listings = simplexml_load_file("file.xml");
foreach ($listings as $listing) {
    echo "endereco: $listing->endereco<br/>";
    $arquivos = $listing->xpath("Media/foto/arquivo");
    foreach ($arquivos as $ar) {
        echo "Imagem: $ar<br/>";
    }
}
```